# XAMPP Error: Facing Error while starting Apache service (Apache Shutdown unexpectedly)

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm trying to start apache from Xampp but facing below error message each time. I have tried all methods like changing ports, Reinstalling Xampp, etc. but nothing is working.

```
Checking default ports...
12:45:22 pm  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
12:45:22 pm  [Apache]   Executing "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
12:45:22 pm  [Apache]   Return code: 0
12:45:22 pm  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:45:25 pm  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Below are the apache error.log files

```
  [Wed Jan 22 12:45:23.946765 2020] [core:warn] [pid 9960:tid 592] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
  [Wed Jan 22 12:45:24.003613 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9960:tid 592] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
  [Wed Jan 22 12:45:24.003613 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9960:tid 592] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Aug 11 2019 12:20:04
  [Wed Jan 22 12:45:24.003613 2020] [core:notice] [pid 9960:tid 592] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
  [Wed Jan 22 12:45:24.015583 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9960:tid 592] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8008
  [Wed Jan 22 12:45:24.600416 2020] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 8008:tid 4] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : AH00404: Child: Unable to read socket data from parent
```

Kindly help me to slve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Edit > Preferences > Shared VMS > Disable Sharing --> and then change port to e.g 8443 and save changes --> restart xampp